# Compress static generated contents using Next JS

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, static

I have generated static files using Next js and uploaded them to Amazon S3. The problem is that generated files such as .js and .css files are not compressed in the way expected by Google Analytics. The error is:

Text-based resources should be served with compression (gzip, deflate or brotli) to minimize total network bytes.

I know that Next js uses Gzip by default but I think I should optimize it.

Comment: Better you describe your use case. I have no idea, what you want to do. As I know, Next.js does not compress anything. Compressing does the CDN (e.g. Vercel). If you generate a complete static site and upload to some CDN, the CDN will take care of compression. If you upload the site to some storage, and you would like to store compressed files, you have to do this on your own.

Comment: Usnig Next 14 after npm run build my static site using SSG is generated in out folder. I uploaded out folder to S3 and checked it as a website. Some of the generated js and css files that are located in out/chunks folder are not optimized and compressed completely.

Comment: Please provide sources. You write: "...I know that Next js uses Gzip by default but I think I should optimize it....". Source? I'm not aware of Next.js compression. You write: "...after npm run build my static site using SSG is generated in out folder...". Do you refere to [Static Exports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)? I don't see compression as a feature. You write: "...Some of the generated js and css files that are located in out/chunks folder are not optimized and compressed completely...". What means "completely"? Some are compressed?

Comment: I have generated my static website using Static Export feature of Next js. I need the generated contents such as CSS and JS files to be compressed and optimized.

Comment: According to this source, I thought it compressed the contents: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/compress

Comment: I see the confusion. Read carefully the first sentence. “By default, Next.js uses gzip to compress rendered content and static files **when using next start or a custom server.**” That means, the server does compression. It does not mean, the generated assets are compressed.

Comment: There is even more confusion. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli#build. "...Both of these values are compressed with gzip. The first load is indicated by green, yellow, or red. Aim for green for performant applications..." This means, the reported sizes refer to compressed sizes. So, I'm pretty confident, that you have to compress the files yourself. Check again your out folder. If the files are not compressed, it should be like this. Test my answer below. If it is a solution, please mark it as so and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading docs, I think this is the right workflow:

1. Build your static site. See: [Static Exports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)
2. Compress your assets. See: [How To Serve GZipped JS and CSS from AWS S3](https://medium.com/@graysonhicks/how-to-serve-gzipped-js-and-css-from-aws-s3-211b1e86d1cd)
3. Deploy on Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

Compression is usually better handled by a CDN such as CloudFront

That being said, to answer your question (at least partially), assuming you are using `output: "export"` in your nextjs 13+ config, and you want to generate the compressed assets (e.g. gzipped .js and .css files) at build time, you can use [CompressionWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) to do this for you.

First, install

```
npm install compression-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

and then change your `next.config.js` (or mjs if your using es6)

```js
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");


const config = {
     // ... other stuff in your config

     /** @type {(config: import('webpack').Configuration, context: import('next/dist/server/config-shared').WebpackConfigContext) => import('webpack').Configuration} */
   webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (!isServer) {
        config.plugins.push(new CompressionPlugin());
      }
      return config
    }
}
```

The `isServer` part is not necessary, just saves some build time.

if you want to customize the compression algo, which files get compressed, compression ratio, etc... check the plugin documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/

on my project, this is a snippet of the output inside `_next/static/chunks`:

```
├── 08548717-91f03a7f6e188aa1.js
├── 08548717-91f03a7f6e188aa1.js.gz
├── 175675d1-a5f998fde19f31c1.js
├── 175675d1-a5f998fde19f31c1.js.gz
├── 2dc05096-775b14766d8fb412.js
├── 2dc05096-775b14766d8fb412.js.gz
```

To my understanding S3 should be able to pickup the `.gz` files by itself.

Please note that here you are using a custom webpack config, this *might* introduce some conflicts with the way that nextjs build works, especially if they change something. So far I had no problems with this approach, just a heads up.

Also keep in mind that the nextjs team is moving towards their own bundler [TurboPack](https://turbo.build/pack) so long term compatibility might be a question.